# Check-boxes Addition ($_POST)

Tags: php

I was wondering how to make it so when I click two check-boxes then submit, a value appears; in this case the wanted value is "15 percent"

I have tried to make it work in several ways & read about the '$_POST' in the PHP manual but can't figure out how to solve this problem

#### PHP Lab 04

```
        <form name="orderform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

            Discount<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="discount" value="student"/>Customer one 15%<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="discount" value="senior"/>Customer two 10%<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="discount" value="klant"/>Customer three 5%



                 <br />   <input type="image" src="button.jpg" value="order" />


        </form>


   <br /> Total discount

    <?php
           if(isset($_POST['discount']))
           {

            if($_POST['discount']=="student")
            {
               echo "15 percent";
            }
            else if($_POST['discount']=="senior")
            {
               echo "10 percent";
            }
            else if($_POST['discount']=="klant")
            {
               echo "5 percent";
            }
            else if($_POST['discount']=="senior" && $_POST['discount']=="klant")
            {
                echo "15 percent";
            }
           }

        ?>
</body>
```

Results of customer two & customer three

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsUqU.png

Comment: You can't have more than one input with the same name. Try `name="discount[]"` to submit the values as array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use radio instead of checkbox try the following:

```
    <form name="orderform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

        Discount<br />
    <input type="radio" name="discount" value="student"/>Customer one 15%<br />
    <input type="radio" name="discount" value="senior"/>Customer two 10%<br />
    <input type="radio" name="discount" value="klant"/>Customer three 5%



             <br />   <input type="image" src="button.jpg" value="order" />


    </form>
```

I assume you only want one of those selected at a time, not multiple.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to do what you mentioned in the comment then you have to do like @5parc mentioned. here is the code, "although I think there is a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do":

```
    <form name="orderform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

        Discount<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="discount[]" value="student"/>Customer one 15%<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="discount[]" value="senior"/>Customer two 10%<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="discount[]" value="klant"/>Customer three 5%



             <br />   <input type="image" src="button.jpg" value="order" />


    </form>


<br /> Total discount

<?php
       if(isset($_POST['discount']))
       {

        if(in_array('senior', $_POST['discount']) && in_array('klant', $_POST['discount'])) {
          echo "15 percent";
        }
        else if(in_array('student', $_POST['discount']))
        {
           echo "15 percent";
        }
        else if(in_array('senior', $_POST['discount']))
        {
           echo "10 percent";
        }
        else if(in_array('klant', $_POST['discount']))
        {
           echo "5 percent";
        }

       }

    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: I want them both selected & want them to give me 15 as answer